# Error creating a view or table via CLI : "Unexpected exception in mk operation: '_Make' object has no attribute 'partitioning_specification'"

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I've just run `gcloud components update` and now cannot create a view or table via the `bq` Python command-line tool.

It returns an error `Unexpected exception in mk operation: '_Make' object has no attribute 'partitioning_specification'`.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is now live. You can run `gcloud components update` to pick up the latest client.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the "bq" tool that was pushed in the most recent build.

We are working on adding some additional testing to catch this type of error.

In the meantime, please do a `gcloud components restore` to restore your previous version of the Google Cloud SDK if you encounter this error and need to create a view or table.